# How can I susbtitute unseasoned rice vinegar for seasoned?

Tags: substitutions, vinegar

I have unseasoned rice vinegar but a recipe that calls for seasoned.  I assume I should add sugar and salt to substitute for seasoned vinegar, but in what proportions would mimic a typical seasoned rice vinegar?

Answer (score 3):

For each cup of vinegar, add 3 tablespoons of sugar and one tablespoon of salt. You may also add a piece of kelp or a pinch of kelp powder. And of course, all of these proportions can be adjusted to taste.

Comment: How did you arrive at this ratio?

Comment: I make it at home. You can also Google "sushi su recipes" and find several with very similar ratios. Some will substitute mirin for the sugar though.

Answer (score 3):

From my favorite Japanese cooking site, JustHungry:

> Mix 1/4 cup of rice vinegar or mild cider vinegar, 1 tablespoon of sugar, 1/2 tablespoon of mirin, sake or sweet brandy, and 1/2 tablespoon of salt. Heat over low heat in a small saucepan, and stir until the sugar and salt have dissolved. This is enough to flavor 4 cups of rice, so adjust the amount according to the amount of rice you have.

[Source](http://justhungry.com/2003/11/japanese_basics_1.html)

Comment: I just tried this, but I used less salt. It's so good I could drink it. I won't, but I could.